# Sorting in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am having the below function in VBA. This function creates drop-down from a range. Now I want to attach the sorting to this. How to create sorting in this

```
Public Sub CORE_SetValidation(ByRef Rng As Range, ByVal Value As String)
    With Rng.Validation
        Call .Delete
        If Value <> "" Then
            Call .Add(Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Value)
            .ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from drop-down list"
            .ErrorTitle = "Value Error"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputMessage = ""
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to sort, the entire range? Before or after deleting? Using VBA or just the sorting option already implemented in excel? Why don't you record a macro when you enable sorting manually in excel and see what that does?

Comment: Sorry I am new to VBA, I need sorting in dropdown after it is created using the above function

Comment: Then try to record a macro whilst setting up sorting, then see what code is generated and apply that to your existing code.

Comment: @Luuklag Its very interesting to have an idea from your comment. But I am really dont know how to do it. Could you provide the details as a new Answer

Comment: Under the developper tab there is a red record button. Just press it, then go set your sorting, press it again to stop the recording. There should be  a new sub in your file with the steps you just recorded.

Comment: Thanks a lot; How easy it is. Macro generated the code. Really interesting to know this

Comment: You will need to sort `Value` before you use it in `.Validation`.  There are many ways of doing it, both within and prior to calling this macro.  (You could sort it after, but that would be less efficient).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks, Yes I have placed the sorting code before the .Validation. Its working fine